# Not sure why I get Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to accomplish with this is to have a URL for the API accessible via Drupal.settings so I can get to it from PhP and js with Drupal 7.41.

I have put this at the top of my custombootstrap.module file:

```
function yourmodule_init(){
    $apiurl="http://dev3.ws.mysite.com/api"
    drupal_add_js(array('yourmodule' => array('myurl' => $apiurl)), array('type' => 'setting'));
    variable_set('myurl',$apiurl);
}
```

In a file called mapLayer.js I use the code like this:

```
var List_Users_Map = function(){
var userId = $('#uid-loged').val();
$('#list-users-gis-map').html('');
//linkedRequests(userId);   // RCD- CAll
$.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.yourmodule.myurl+'linked_users_gis/x-api-key/blahhhhhhhhhhTq4SWuCiLONePNfschNft',
    data:{uid:userId},
    type: 'GET',
    ...
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myurl' of undefined can be seen here in chrome dev tools.  It looks like it gets to 'yourmodule' but no further.

```
    http://imgur.com/cu4jtw6
```

Comment: are you using a drupal behavoir ? otherwise settings won't be populated

Comment: Per the docs you should not be using hook_init to add JS or CSS as it will not be fired on cached pages. Instead use your theme functions such as `theme_preprocess_html(&$vars)` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) are the docs.

Answer (score 0):

your init hook seems to be wrong, change the function name to `custombootstrap_init`,
where the init hook is not the best choice for adding a js setting ..

in drupal it's good practice to use a behavoir, so wrap your js code like:

```
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavoir = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    ..
  }
};
```

and then just use `settings.yourmodule.myurl`

Comment: when I change the function name to custombootstrap_init I get the same error,

Comment: try a different hook and make sure it gets hit